# Asking for user input before DataTable button is submitted using the TableTools extension

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using the [TableTools](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation) extension of [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). I know this extension is retired, but I'm working on an existing application that's already utilizing it.

I'm trying to display a modal window to capture some user input before the button is submitted; however, I can't find any way in the documentation as far as how to do it. The button is configured to submit to a PHP endpoint via Ajax.